# Third-Party apps get verified whenever I turn on my Mac after writing this code

Tags: macos

I was doing something on my mac and I wrote this `csrutil enable --without kext` code in the recovery terminal window on my mac. After that when I turned on the mac, all the third-party apps got verified again.

I thought that this would only happen one time. But then whenever I restart or turn my mac on, all the third-party apps get verified again. I know this is not a big deal but it really takes a lot of my time.

Do you guys know the code to fix this? Is it `csrutil enable --without kext`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring MacOS and its utilities. [apple.se] would be a better place for questions like this.

Comment: If `enable` started it, maybe `disable` will stop it.